# Function doesn't read global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

I'm having a litte problem with Javascript and global variables.
According to an article I read a few minutes ago when searching for a solution, variables defined outside a function are global and can be used all over the document. 
Well, this doesn't seem to work for me. Basically, even why I try to simplify the process to this:

```
var list_amount = 1;
function createElements() {
    window.alert('0');
    var cintfa_list_top = $("<div>").attr({"id":"intfa_list_top"});
    $('#intfa_list').empty()
    $('#intfa_list').append(cintfa_list_top);
    var j=0;
    window.alert('1');
    for (j=0;j<list_amount;j++) {
        window.alert('2');
            ......
            ....
            ..
```

I get the window.alert for 0 and 1, but not for 2. When I set a window.alert(list_amount) inside the function, it returns undefined. Shouldn't the global variable work inside the function as well? And if I misunderstood something, is there a way to make variables global for functions as well without having to add them to the function parameters?

Comment: What's outside of createElements()?  Is that function inside another function?  If so, list_amount wouldn't be global, it would be local to that function

Comment: Are you calling createElements before declaring list_amount?

Comment: That's it - luke got it - it's a hoisting issue.  The declaration is hoisted to the top, set to undefined, then if you call createElements before the line that sets it to 1, it'll still be undefined

Comment: The function is called by the body onload attribute, but even when I try calling the function with a button after the page loads, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your code that hangs the script. As it is, closing for and function works very well (also commenting out $, as it's not defined here).

Check in Firebug or Chrome/Opera javascript console for errors.

LE: After seeing jsfiddle.net/ALd2b/2 you should call the function after variable assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code http://jsfiddle.net/lastrose/ALd2b/ and it seems to work fine.
Only thing I can think is where it is all defined.

Comment: Hmm great, then it might be some code error waaay off somewhere else. Javascript bugfixing ahoy.. Thanks for the testing :)

Comment: No, sadly, it doesn't. That would be an easy fix.

Comment: I found the mistake, it was way earlier in the document where I forgot to define a 2D Array before assigning values to it, my guess is it that even though it doesn't show up in the function up to that point, it somehow glitched everything?
Either way, thanks for the help to everyone :)